# Keep PhantomJS browser open between test scenarios

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, cucumber-serenity

We´re using the stack Java + cucumber + selenium + phantomjs, everything works fine, but we notice that phantomjs is restarting the ghostDriver for every single scenario which take time. I just wondering is it possible to just keep PhantomJS browser open between scenarios of my test?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help:

[Faster Cucumber startup: Keep the PhantomJS browser open between tests](https://medium.com/@sharetribe/faster-cucumber-startup-keep-the-phantomjs-browser-open-between-tests-81daed0159a9#.bt12un9vr)